# Escaping get parameters in smarty

Tags: php, smarty, xss

I have inherited a code base with PHP, MySQL and Smarty and I'm implementing a menu system for the web application.

I have a URL as such: `http://example.com/?url=some/page`

In my database i store the string `'some/page'` and map it to a file `'some/path/dir/mypage.php'` and when visiting the URL the file is included using `include()` in a PHP script that fetches the `url` parameter.

The code contains forms that uses GET parameters to post data and if I'm on a page such as `http://example.com/?url=myform/add` I need to include a hidden input field with the name `url` where the value is `myform/add` so that the form can post back the results to the correct page.

Smarty has syntax like `{$smarty.get.url}`that fetches the url GET parameter and outputs it. This leads to my hidden input field looking like this:

`<input type="hidden" name="url" value="{$smarty.get.url}">`

Now, I realise that I should clean the url parameter before printing it as the value but I'm not sure how. Using `{$smarty.get.url|escape:'url'}` escapes the `/` character to `%2F` resulting in:

`<input type="hidden" name="url" value="myform%2Fadd">`

and when I submit the form it is converted to `%252F` giving me the url:

`http://example.com/?url=some%252Fpage`

Since the `/` is supposed to be a valid query parameter I don't see why it is encoded at all in the first place. Using `/` in the query is also important for me to allow the users to understand the url in a better way with clean url's.

So the question becomes, how should I handle the get parameter in smarty to keep the `/` as it is while at the same time protecting from XSS-attacks?

I'm not worried about the PHP-side of things since I have good protection after reading $_GET['url'].

EDIT: Perhaps I don't have to escape it at all since the php script gets the url parameter and if the parameter doesn't match what is stored in the database, the form is never loaded and thus the get parameter is never printed in the hidden input field. I still think this question is relevant for other uses though.

Comment: Leave the escape parameter blank like so: `{$smarty.get.url|escape}`. This would apply htmlspecialchars instead of rawrurlencode (escape:'url'). Use {...|escape:'url'} only if you want to escape an URI component. You can also set auto escaping for all variables. Just add this option `$smarty->escape_html = true;`. If you set this and want to avoid escaping for a single variable you can do it like so `{$noescape nofilter}`.